# gasLimit 5000 on private Ethereum geth node

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, gas-limit

**Problem:**
I've upgraded my geth node to the latest version (1.9.0-unstable). The block gasLimit of the node is fixed at 5000:

```
eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit

5000
```

When I try to send a transaction, I get the following error:

```
Error: exceeds block gas limit
```

**Attempted fixes:** I have tried to alter the default gasLimit value in the `genesis.json`:

```
"gasLimit": "0xffffffff"
```

From geth node command line option:

```
--targetgaslimit '9000000000000'
```

---

**Point to note**: On previous versions, i.e, before upgrading, the block gasLimit returned by the node was much higher and it let me  deploy contracts and perform transactions.

```
eth.getBlock("latest").gasLimit

4286582786
```

Answer (score 5):

As @fixanoid stated in his answer you can change the gas limit in the `genesis.json`.

**But** this isn't an optimal solution in my opinion. You are better off using a specific flag for your miner.

Geth has the `--targetgaslimit` flag that will cause your miner(s) to move step by step towards a given gas limit. Only a certain increase is allowed per block. Typically `prev limit/1024`. So it might take some time to get it where you want it to be. Obviously a larger change results in the block not being accepted.

Besides specifying the `--targetgaslimit` flag you also have to make your node `--mine` in your private blockchain (**Obviously**).

**EDIT**: How are you sending the transactions? What gas limit are you currently specifying? The minimum for a transaction is 21000. If you are invoking a contract with a fallback function even more gas is needed. Make sure you have enough ETH to pay for the gas.

The problem might be that the error message is **flawed**.

Comment: As stated in the question, neither genesis.json gasLimit setting nor miner flag is working with last go-ethereum version

Comment: You started mining?

Comment: Take a look at my edit as well. I am quite certain that the problem isn't really with you block gas limit directly.

Answer (score 2):

3 things to try:

- Avoid using unstable versions, switch to the last stable Elasa (v1.9.6)
- You may have to increase the gas a bit when deploying contracts, because of new versions of solidity where gas calculation changes
- Using a gas price oracle is sometimes needed

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to set very high limit for gas in the genesis config file like so: "gasLimit": "0xE0000000". Alternatively, run a client optimized for private nets: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum. Default gas limit is in billions.